# "All that is needing" vs. "all that is needed"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, past-participles, participles, present-participles

I've read the following quote from *Game of Thrones*:

> Opening your eyes is all that is **needing**. The heart lies and the head plays tricks with us, but the eyes see true.

English is not my mother tongue, so I'd like to understand why *needing* is used here instead of *needed*.

Comment: It's an archaic construction, intended to sound archaic in context.

Comment: There is an interesting relationship between the words "need" and "want," "needing" and "wanting."  As a kid, when I heard Psalm 23 (in the nineteenth book of the Old Testament of The Holy Bible) being read in the King James Version (1769 via 1611), I was kind of confused by this wording: "The LORD is my shepherd; I shall not want."  Why wouldn't someone want the LORD as their shepherd, I wondered to myself!  Today, a decent paraphrase would be: "[With] the LORD as my shepherd, I have everything I need."  The "not want" in this case means "I'll not be in need."

Answer (score 1):

As John said, the structure is intentionally archaic. Moreover, in my experience the usual archaic construction would be *is needful*, so my guess is that the author is trying to not only make it sound old, but also from a different world (i.e., the world of Game of Thrones), because this isn't a construction commonly found in modern OR old English.

Comment: How does it convey the sense of a "different" world, and what do you even mean by that?

Comment: Edited to clarify.